# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object -php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to access json decode data's array elements. I'm getting an error while trying to access. Below is my php code with output decoded json data.

```
<?php
.
.
.

$json = $response;
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_output);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [alph_id] => 02adb5b4-d2fe-4a46-8798-1e2b876b2055
            [name] => Michael
            [s_id] => 1462339266273
            [avg_at] => 12.060000419617
            [distance] => 0
            [sw] => OFF
            [set_no] => 1
            [final_at] => 18.700000762939

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [alph_id] => 02adb5b4-d2fe-4a46-8798-1e2b876b2055
            [name] => John
            [s_id] => 1462339266273
            [avg_at] => 12.060000413454
            [distance] => 0
            [sw] => OFF
            [set_no] => 1
            [final_at] => 19.700000762939
        )
        .
        .
        .
```

I tried to access alph_id element, but its shows an error.

```
echo $json_output[0]->alph_id;  
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I think i correctly access the array element. What is wrong with that?

Thanks...

Comment: you have associative array, so try `$json_output[0]['alph_id']`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I suggest making that an answer and explaining why it says "Array" in "[0] => Array".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You make the json decode for associative array by using the `true` as second parameter.

So you need to access it as `$json_output[0]['alph_id']`.

If you make like this,

```
$json_output = json_decode($json);
```

This json_decode returns the result as Object, then it should be,

```
$json_output[0]->alph_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You used true in the second parameter of json_decode

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

when you define this should access to indexes with following structure

```
$json_output[0]['alph_id'];
```